# other way can encode array into string and decode it back to array?

Tags: php

Does anyone know there have any other way that (by not using json_encode and json_decode) to encode an array into string then decode it back into string? I remember there have another call unlis...(cannot really remember the name :( )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php).